# 'Check' object has no attribute 'image' while using sightengine api

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, api

I am using sightengine API to detect child sexual abuse in images. In order to do that I am trying to detect the nudity level in an image using sightengine API. The following example is provided in the documentation itself.

```
from sightengine.client import SightengineClient

client = SightengineClient('api_user', 'api_key')
output = client.check('nudity').image('https://d3m9459r9kwism.cloudfront.net/img/examples/example7.jpg')
```

Apart from copying the same code I am getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "driver.py", line 3, in <module>
    output = client.check('nudity').image('https://d3m9459r9kwism.cloudfront.net/img/examples/example7.jpg')
AttributeError: 'Check' object has no attribute 'image'
```

I have used both Python 2 and Python 3 for the same code but both raise the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try This:

```
from sightengine.client import SightengineClient

client = SightengineClient('API user', 'API secret')

checkNudity = client.check('nudity')

output1 = checkNudity.set_url('https://d3m9459r9kwism.cloudfront.net/img/examples/example7.jpg')

print(output1)
```